# Set TabItem header style in Silverlight when using MEF

Tags: silverlight, styles, mef, tabcontrol

This is my tabcontrol:

```
  <sdk:TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainTabControl">
  </sdk:TabControl>
```

As you can see there aren't any TabItems at design time since i'm using MEF, and the items are created dynamically.

How should I set the TabItem header style ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following. Create an ItemTemplate for the tabitems and then set the headertemplate of that template

```
<sdk:TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainTabControl">
   <sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <sdk:TabItem HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TabControl>
```

Greetings

Comment: Thanks Rikkos, but it didn't work for me. in run time it seems that the template did not been applied.

Comment: @Erez This seems wierd. I've checked with the toolkit and they do it like this 

`<sdk:TabItem>
<sdk:TabItem.header>
 <TextBlock Text="Something">
</sdk:TabItem.header>
</Sdk:TabItem>`